# Is the score function form of ALiBi, a positional encoding in Deep Learning, always lower triangular?

Tags: deep-learning, transformer

I have a question about the score function of ALiBi (Attention with Linear Biases), which is a positional encoding method introduced by the following paper:

[TRAIN SHORT, TEST LONG: ATTENTION WITH LINEAR BIASES ENABLES INPUT LENGTH EXTRAPOLATION](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12409.pdf)

According to Figure 3 in the paper, the score function form is a lower triangular matrix.

If in the masked multi-head attention in the Transformer model (e.g., in decoder layer), it is no problem.

On the contrary, I'd like to know about its use in a general format, in other words, in normal multi-head attention (e.g. encoder layer).

Is it also a lower triangular matrix? If not, what form does the linear bias term have?